# Some questions sabout Typo3 shorcut and some doubts about the page structure in the demo website

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am very new in `Typo3 world` (I came from Joomla and WordPress), I am reading the official documentation and I have some doubts related to the use of the **shortcuts special page**

I have installed the **introductionpackage-6.1.1.zip package** and I have started the related demo web site.

So I open the backend and I go into the **Pages** backend module.

Ok, I am finding some important difference from what I can read here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/GeneralPrinciples/SpecialPages/Index.html

these difference are:

1. The root of my website is Welcom to Typo3 and not Home (as in the documentation) but maybe is only a naming thing...
2. My root is not a shortcut but the first page (that is named Home and not "Welcom on Typo3") is a shortcut that seems to point to nowhere: if I show this page by the contestual menu I obtain the main Apache message: "It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

I attach an immage of what I see in my pages module of my backend after the installation of Typo3 on my Ubuntu system:

As you can see I have that the **root page** is named **Welcom to TYPO3** and this is  **not a shortcut** (but editing it is signed as "standard" page) and the **home** is a child of the  page root page and is a shortcut.

[image]

Why? Is these thing normal? Are changed something from when the documentation was written?

Comment: Use TYPO3 bootstrap. It much better and transparent, as it uses Fedext system https://github.com/Ecodev/bootstrap_package

Comment: mmm what is this TYPO3 bootstrap, is it an additional package or is used to install typo3 in another way? have I to reinstall the CMS?

Comment: Standalone compilation. Follow github instructions to install.

Comment: Update for 2019: You can use the "Introduction Package" as explained in "Getting Started" and "Installation Guide". It is based on the bootstrap_package by Benjamin Kott. The recently updated "Getting Started Tutorial" for TYPO3 9 should be more in sync with the "Introduction Package". In any case, you are welcome to write an issue for documentation errors or unclarity: https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Tutorial-GettingStarted/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the `Getting Started Code Spring in Venlo` last year, we change the page structure a bit. The documentation you are using still refers to the `TYPO3 CMS 4.4 Introduction Package`, especially the screenshots are all from that time.

We are currently updating the manual to be up2date when `TYPO3 CMS 6.2 LTS` will be released.

Now to the page structure:
The root page is the actual page holding the content. Therefore it is named `Welcome to TYPO3`. Below that page is a dummy page named `Home` which is a shortcut the the former page.
This had the advantage that visitors do not get redirected if they visit the home page as it was with the earlier structure of those two pages switched.

The new structure works fine. If you open that page (`Home`)from the backend, then you will get redirected to the root shortcut destination (`Welcome to TYPO3`).
If this redirect fails, then something is strange about your setup. Please carefully check the URL in your browser and see if it matches the URL if your frontend site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear response, now it is more clear for me.
The only thing that I am not understanding is why, when I show the Home dummy page, it appears me the Apache standard hello message...or rather why when I show the Home dummy page it open the link: localhost (that is the root of my web server) and not the URL http://localhost/Typo3/ (that is the root of my TYPO3 website) Tn Andrea

Comment: This is properly a misconfiguration of your ``.htaccess `` or ``mod_rewrite`` is not active on your server.

Comment: mod_rewrite seems to be activated on my server, now I will provide to analyze my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

1- It's just a page title, you can name the page as you want
2- I'm not sure i understant the issue (maybe if you show give us a screenshot of your backend..) but what you should have is : the root page should be a shortcut to the home page, so if a refer to the screenshots in the link you provided, the root (Home) should link to the home page (Welcome to TYPO3).

It could be some differences between the doc and the actual state of TYPO3, as it is evoluating pretty fast in this year. But the differences are not major.

if you have further questions do not hesitate to ask them.

Comment: I have edited my original message including an immage of what I see

Comment: You're right, it's weird. Home should be the root and welcome should be the first sub page. Well you can change it. First make Home a page instead of a shortcut. Move the contents in the "welcome page" from the root to the first page, and then rename the two pages and make home a shortcut to the first subpage